# What is the origin of Doom's helmet?

Tags: doom

I was wondering what Doomguy's helmet is made up or or is based on: for example, a children's helmet. Do you know the origin of Doom's helmet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

This particular cover art was created by Don Ivan Punchatz, who sadly passed away in 2009. It's an original work on his part. As for where he got his inspiration, one can only speculate.

You should also note that this is not the only rendition of our space marine hero, see for example the PSX boxart and art for DOOM II (though one could speculate he's the same guy sans-helmet as he's now back on earth):
[image][image]

Comment: He's obviously wearing the helmet so that he can breathe.  See how the helmeted picture is outside, but the other two are indoors?

Comment: Thanks. The only way to know how he get inspiration is to ask the artist. :)

Comment: In game, the player is always wearing the helmet... you'd know this if you've ever played Deathmatch. :P

Comment: I thought the Space Marine from Aliens were what inspired Doomguy's look, including the helmets.